# Getting datatypes of 23 and 24 when trying to convert MySQL to SQL Server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to convert a MySQL database to SQL Server 2008.  When I ran the import wizard, I would get errors like:

> The data type could not be assigned to the column "birth_date" in "SQL Server Native Client 10.0

So, I look at the mappings and some of the columns are trying to convert to data type 23 and 24:
[image]

There's about 200+ tables with this problem.  I am wondering if there is some way I can correct this other than going into each table in the import wizard and changing the type manually.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give us a hint about what the data type is in the MySQL table?

Comment: Date and time, actually.